# Getting count of residents in each country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a Users table, and each user has a country_id (the list of countries is stored in another table).

I want to display a list of each country and how many members it has, ie:

```
Canada: 16
Romania: 12
USA: 9
```

I was using some raw SQL, but the move to postgres was messy, so I'd like to use a cleaner implementation. Is there a nice 'railsy' way to go about getting said list?

Comment: please share what you have tried,along with the table schema

Comment: ActiveRecord methods group and count should be all you need here.

Comment: What I have is fairly involved (and probably overly complex), so I'd like to just go from the ground floor here. I'm sure this is a relatively common type of query, so I'd like any and all advice! You can imagine the table schema is just a User table with an ID, name and country_id column, and a Country table with an id and name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should return a hash with `country_id => count` pairs:

```
@users_by_country = User.group(:country_id).count
#=> { 1 => 104, 2 => 63, ... }
```

The generated SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, country_id AS country_id FROM `users` GROUP BY country_id
```

And in your view:

```
<% @countries.each do |country| %>
  <%= country.name %>: <%= @users_by_country[country.id] %>
<% end>
```

Answer (score 2):

though you have not provided any detail . so its hard to answer exaclty, but may be this will help

```
User.group(:country_id).count
```

Comment: Definitely it. @Stefan beat you by a minute, so I've gotta give him the check, but you get an upvote and my eternal gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Countries model and you want to do it a little differently so that it is more human readable you could use .map.

Countries.map{|o| { Country: o.name, members: o.members.count } }

Obviously you need to have the associations.  If countries is just a field on User then this will not work.

BR